# Does anyone know how do i get the list of all the applications installed in phone that can run audio files in react-native?

Tags: react-native, audio

I want to create a functionality in react-native app such that on pressing a particular button, it should get me to the "open with" window, and that window should fetch me the list of all the installed applications in the phone which can run audio files. How can i get such list?

Answer (score 0):

On a Android system, that "Open with" screen pops up when:

1. The user have more than one application that can play that `specific audio format`(Because it's not every app that can run every audio format).
2. The user did not set-up a default app to open the audio format.

So, You should just use a library like [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) to open the file for you, like as follow:

```js
RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(fileLocation, mimeType)
```

And android will take care of picking the right app for you.

In case this answer does not satisfy you, you can get a list of apps using [react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking](https://github.com/HydromanAG/react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking), but there's no information about wich ones can run an audio file, and maybe IOS will have some restrictions about what can be done, so your best option is to let the system do that for you!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually i forgot to mention that i was looking for a solution in Expo without ejecting And fortunately i found the solution in Expo.

Comment: Solution : in Expo it can be done by using "expo-intent-launcher". install and import the package first and then use the code. 1) import * as IntentLauncher from "expo-intent-launcher"; 2)  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER")